# Understanding this theorem on Hessian matrices

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, hessian-matrix

I am having a hard time understanding this theorem on Hessian matrix from the book Advanced Calculus by Patrick Fitzpatrick. Can someone tell me what is going on or refer me to another source. Also, is there any good sites to study real analysis? Thanks

[image]

Comment: At a glance it seems to express a directional derivative in terms of the partial derivatives (gradient) and an analogous expression for a second order directional derivative (in terms of the Hessian).  For some online resources, see the site [RealNotComplex](https://realnotcomplex.com/) which has been featured in Community Ad posts on Math.SE.

Comment: The second book here is good for analysis: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/math-521-522-basic-undergraduate-analysis-advanced-calculus/. (a) is immediate from the chain rule. To prove (b) you expand (a) in coordinates and use the chain rule again. The above book does these things in some detail.